# How to rid of pandas import error on LinuxOS?

Tags: python, pandas, ubuntu, importerror, sudo

I need to install pandas on a LinuxOS. Initially, I used
`sudo apt-get install python3-pandas`
It looked like the installation was complete but then I switch to Thonny and import pandas and get this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/_init_.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/compat/_init_.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/compat/numpy/_init_.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas.util.version import Version
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/util/_init_.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.util._decorators import (  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.properties import cache_readonly  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/libs/init_.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.interval import Interval
  File "pandas/_libs/interval.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.interval
ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 44 from C header, got 40 from PyObject
```

I have been looking all over the internet and tried doing everything anyone suggested but it persists. I uninstalled and reinstalled it using `sudo pip3 install pandas`. Pandas right now is v1.3.4. Tried upgrading it, the prompt said "Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade". I am facing a similar issue with installation and importation of trackpy library too but let's just focus on pandas for now. Didn't want to go for Conda as that is huge and I have limited space (this is a RPi I'm working with).

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall `numpy`?

Comment: No I did not try that separately. But I uninstalled and reinstalled pandas again and it's working this time. I am not sure what changed.. it is still giving some warnings, but it is working.